# Adding state to an Either

Tags: haskell

I have a function which is something like `myFunction` below:

```
data MyError = E1 | E2

f s = if s == "" then Left E1 else Right $ reverse s

g = (fmap reverse) . f

myFunction :: String -> Either MyError (String, String)
myFunction s = do
    s1 <- f s
    s2 <- g s1
    return (s2, s2)
```

So it calls various other functions which are also in the `Either` monad, so everything is OK.

Now I have a situation where the type of one of the functions, say `g`, changes to

```
g :: CPRG r => r -> String -> (Either MyError String, r)
```

For reference, the "real-world" code is the `decode` function [here](https://github.com/tekul/jose-jwt/blob/7cb98fe59d4512e1ca2120d0c167bbf565fe5215/Jose/Jwt.hs#L34) and the function that changes is `Jwe.rsaDecode` (I'm adding RSA blinding to the decryption function).

As a result, `myFunction` needs to have the same type, so that I can pass in the `CPRG` and return it. I'm having trouble seeing how I can carry on using something like the `Either` monad in combination with passing the RNG, and still be able to extract the final state of the RNG in both the failure and success cases, so that it can be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type

```
r -> (Either e a, r)
```

is a monad transformer. In particular, it's the [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) transformer

```
newtype ExceptT e m a = ExceptT (m (Either e a))
```

We'll specialize it for `State` such that

```
r -> (Either e a, r)
~
ExceptT e (State r) a
```

---

So what is a monad transformer? Well, it turns out that often when you take two monads together and stack them you end up with yet another monad. It is not always the case and is a bit tricky to do in general (unlike `Applicative` where stacks of `Applicative` functors are always yet again `Applicative` functors).

That said, the library linked above, `mtl`, demonstrates a list of common "transformers" which encode common ways of stacking monads. Thus, `ExceptT` is one of these "recipes" and it is designed such that `ExceptT e m a` is a monad so long as `m` is also a `Monad`.

So now we can create a new type alias

```
type M r a = ExceptT MyError (State r) a
```

and write `g` as a function like

```
g' :: CPRG r => String -> M r String
g' s = do
  r <- lift get                    -- lift "lifts" State monad computations up
  let (e, r') = g r s
  lift $ put r'
  either throwError return e       -- here we generalize an Either
                                   -- into the M monad.
```

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could expand on this please? I have used monad transformers a bit, but I'm not very familiar with them. Why is `r -> (Either e a, r)` a monad transformer, for example? And why is it `ExceptT`? How would I use this in practice?

Comment: I added a bit more detail—does this help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I worked out that by using something like `flip runState rng $ runExceptT` I can switch to the type you've given here. I've now ground to a halt with the original code which sequences a series of these calls against a list of inputs, and filters for a successful result - previously the code used `map`, but I can't do that anymore and mapM will stop at the first failure. However, that's another question :).

Comment: You might want to take a look at `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` :)

Comment: Doesn't `sequence` have the same behaviour as `mapM` in that respect? e.g. `sequence [Nothing, Nothing, Just 1, Nothing] = Nothing` whereas I want to extract the `Just 1` ? I've managed to get it working by suppressing the errors and changing the return value type to a `Maybe`, then filtering the resulting list. I'll refine things as I go along. For now I'm just happy it works :).

Comment: Oh, yes, apologies. I misunderstood. You may want to try `msum`.